# How to specify the order of columns generated in the excel sheet when exporting from Salesforce using DataLoader?

Tags: data-loader

I want that the exported csv file has a particular format of columns. Eg I want the first Column in the sheet to be "Name' second as "address' and so on..

Answer (score 3):

If you run the dataloader in batch mode from the command line, you can specify a properties file to map the columns.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_columns.htm

Alternatively you can use a service like Dataloader.io that allows you order the column.

https://dataloader.io/exporting-data-salesforce