# Why are the columns of the SOQL query result not in the order of the fields in the SELECT?

Tags: soql, data-loader

Although exporting using the data loader,
Why does the result of SOQL query do not become the order of the selected fields?

Example.
Data Loader
Step 3: Edit your query
SELECT
  Id,
  Name,
  xxx1,
  xxx2
FROM
  Account

execute
↓
result
↓
Id, Name, xxx2, xxx1 ← It is different from the order specified by select

If the data loader can not do the order in which the items are specified, can you see the regularity?

Comment: Not really sure why it does that, but that begs the question...why does the order of returned fields matter?

Comment: You may be interested in [How to specify the order of columns generated in the excel sheet when exporting from Salesforce using DataLoader?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66467/how-to-specify-the-order-of-columns-generated-in-the-excel-sheet-when-exporting?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: I believe, by default, the Data Loader reorders the results based on the schema definition of the object (so Id is always first, Name is always second, other standard fields follow, then custom fields). SOQL inherently doesn't change the order of the fields in the query that I've ever seen (also, not mentioned in the documentation). Try your same query in the Developer Console (Your Name > Developer Console > Query) to see if you get the fields back in the selected order.

Answer (score 1):

My Java is a bit rusty, but I think the answer can be found in [SOQLMapper.java](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/blob/75032a9bdc2ae32720980a3537bd0b6363431da7/src/main/java/com/salesforce/dataloader/mapping/SOQLMapper.java#L70) and the parent class [Mapper.java](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/blob/75032a9bdc2ae32720980a3537bd0b6363431da7/src/main/java/com/salesforce/dataloader/mapping/Mapper.java#L86).

SOQLMapper.java:

```
public SOQLMapper(PartnerClient client, Collection<String> columnNames, Field[] fields, String mappingFileName)
        throws MappingInitializationException {
    super(client, columnNames, fields, mappingFileName);
}
```

Mapper.java...

```
protected Mapper(PartnerClient client, Collection<String> columnNames, Field[] fields, String mappingFileName)
        throws MappingInitializationException {
    \\...
    Set<String> daoColumns = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    if (columnNames != null) daoColumns.addAll(columnNames);
    this.daoColumns = new CaseInsensitiveSet(Collections.unmodifiableSet(daoColumns));
    putPropertyFileMappings(mappingFileName);
    \\...
}
```

It appears the selected columns make there way into an unordered TreeSet.